# PHP move_uploaded_file() failing on host

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script that uploads some files through php's move_uploaded_file().

Tested on my localhost it works fine. The problem arises when trying to do the same thing on a host. I already red all the topics in that matter here - but none of them solved my problem.

CODE:

```
<?php
$folder = 'img';
if (isset($_FILES['test'])) {
    if (is_writable($folder))
        echo 'Writable';
    else
        echo 'IMG is not writable';

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['test']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['test']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $folder . '/' . $name)) {
        echo 'File was uploaded';
    }
    else {
        echo 'File was not uploaded';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No file - no operation';
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="Test" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

MESSAGE is as follows:

Writable
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php9E75.tmp' to 'img/20130113_114901.jpg' in F:\hshome\ctc-ultralife\ultralife.com\new\admin\index_files\function\test2.php on line 11
File was not uploaded

Folder seems writable. Even if the file is not uploaded, it is created with the specified name in the folder (even if it is an empty file).

I do not know the absolute path of the server - it is not mine.

Your help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a file permission problem, since the temp dir is in C:\

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to give an absolute path to the move_uploaded_file function.

EDIT:

If you don't know the absolute path, you can use the `__DIR__` constant to make up an absolute path.

Assuming you've the `img` folder in the `function` folder, you can write something like this:

```
$fullPath = __DIR__ . '/img/' . $name;
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fullPath)) {
    echo 'File was uploaded';
} else { // ... }
```

In order to understand the real problem, you've to look into the error log.

Comment: Tried that now as well (even though I was forced to use dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)). Still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: complete stab in the dark. I don't know if this is the case, as I don't work on Windows servers.

It may be that the `/` needs to be a `\`. I don't think Windows handles the slash being the other way. That would explain why it can find your directory, but not the file within it.

Comment: I tried (escaping the \\). That does not work either. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're even using a \, it looks like you're using a / (opposite direction).

Comment: Yes, I did. Then, upon your advice, I switched it to "\\" - in order to escape it and use the \. This method still behaves exactly like the / one. A file with the specified name IS created in the desired folder, still it has no content. I also tried uploading the file in the same directory as the script. Same result. Thanks